# Error trying To Read MySQL Table using PySpark

Tags: python, mysql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm currently trying to read from MySQl in Pycharm using Pyspark. My goal is to read the data and load it in HDFS. This is the start of it.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Read MySQL Table Demo - Application Started...")
    spark = SparkSession \
       .builder \
       .appName("Read MySQL Table Demo") \
       .config("spark.jars", "file:///home/amel/Downloads/mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar") \
       .config("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "file:///home/amel/Downloads/mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar") \
       .config("spark.executor.extraLibrary", "file:///home/amel/Downloads/mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar") \
       .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "file:///home/amel/Downloads/mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar") \
       .enableHiveSupport() \
       .getOrCreate()


    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel( " ERROR " )

    mysql_db_driver_class = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    table_name = "mock3"
    host_name = "localhost"
    port_no = str(3306)
    user_name = "Amel"
    password = "Amel@-1998"
    database_name = "testDb"

mysql_select_query= None
mysql_select_query = "(select * from" + table_name + ") as users"
print("Printing mysql_select_query:")
print(mysql_select_query)

mysql_jdbc_url = "jdbc:mysql://" + host_name + " :" + port_no + "/" + database_name
print("Printing JDBC Url:" + mysql_jdbc_url)

trans_detail_tbl_data_df = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
.option("url", mysql_jdbc_url) \
.option("driver", mysql_db_driver_class) \
.option("dbtable ", mysql_select_query) \
.option("user", user_name) \
.option("password", password) \
.load()

trans_detail_tbl_data_df.show(10, False)

print("Read MySQL Table Demo = Application Completed.")
```

**These are the errors**

```
/home/amel/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/bin/python /home/amel/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/Hello.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amel/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/Hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/home/amel/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/home/amel/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 31, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/home/amel/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/accumulators.py", line 97, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/home/amel/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 71, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/home/amel/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 145, in <module>
  File "/home/amel/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 126, in _make_cell_set_template_code
TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I want to read the data that is in MySQl first. After that works,I plan to load the data into HDFS. Before I could move on to the next Step I am facing these errors

Answer (score 0):

So to read the mySQL data using python, I used this:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='Amel',
    password='Amel@-1998',
    port='3306',
    database='testDb'
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute('SELECT * FROM mock3')
users = mycursor.fetchall()
for user in users:
    print(user)
```

and I also added Mysql-connector-python

Comment: Unclear how this answers your question since it isn't Spark code can cannot write a cursor's data to HDFS